# Getting XML version node using VTD-XML in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, vtd-xml

I'm parsing an XML document with VTD-XML library and need to get version tag from the document.

My document looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rootNode>
     <items>
        <item>
            <name>XXX</name>
            <lastName>YYY</lastName>
            <number>1234</number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>AAA</name>
            <lastName>BBB</lastName>
            <number>5678</number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>CCC</name>
            <lastName>DDD</lastName>
            <number>9012</number>
        </item>
     </items>
</rootNode>
```

I need to get this line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I've never used this library but [the documentation](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/userGuide/6.html) mentions a token `TOKEN_DEC_ATTR_VAL`. Since you have used the library you should be able to find out how to access it by this name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in VTD-XML. But the following answer explains how to do it in DOM. *(For other readers: if DOM is not an option, then please ignore this answer)*

Please note that the `version` attribute of the `xml` node, refers to the version of the applied XML standard. Just to avoid confusion, it does not act as a revision number for the content of the document.

**That being said, you can use the [`Document#getXmlVersion`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getXmlVersion()) method**
Similarly, there is also a `getXmlEncoding()` and `getXmlStandalone()`

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("myFile.xml"));

String version = document.getXmlVersion();
String encoding = document.getXmlEncoding();
boolean standalone = document.getXmlStandalone();
```

You could print them like this:

```
System.out.println("<?xml version=\"" + version + "\" encoding=\"" + encoding + "\" standalone=\"" + (standalone? "yes" : "no") + "\" ?>");
```

**EDIT:**

In answer to the question: "How to detect if version was specified or not".

The `version` attribute is stored in a private field inside the `DocumentImpl`, and internally it is `null` when the version is not specified. In the `org.apache.xerces.dom` implementation, the getter provides the default value:

```
public String getXmlVersion() {
    return (version == null)?"1.0":version;
}
```

Unfortunately there are no getters to get the nullable form of the `version` field. But **you could access it using reflection**:

```
Field versionField = document.getClass().getDeclaredField("version");
versionField.setAccessible(true);
String version = versionField.get(document);
if (version == null) 
{ 
  System.out.println("version was not specified")
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to get XML Declaration line, and check if it's valid? I may do it without VTD-XML. Your example is working but I need to get whole line.

Comment: Thanks :) -- if you have `version`, `encoding` and `standalone`, then you have everything really. There are no other possible attributes for the `<?xml ...?>` tag. (Also (afaik) DOM is not capable of detecting the order in which these attributes were specified. Because it shouldn't matter really anyway.)

Comment: Cool I think to do it like this but When there is no decleration line, .getXmlVersion() method returns 1.0. If there is no line I need to handle it.

Comment: Indeed, it falls back to the "default". (And `version` has only been mandatory since xml standard 1.1 ; so without it, it defaults to 1.0). --> I'll check if there's a way to detect this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the token "1.0", get the TOKEN_DEC_ATTR_NAME token index corresponding to "version" the next one (index+1) is the one. Just iterate thru the tokens with the right token type and test the index value with built-in methods of Vtdnav class.